# ActionPerformed different buttons on different JTextArea

Tags: java, button, console

I have 2 JTextArea (j1, j2); j1 works as a console java input while j2 works as console output. I also have 2 buttons (b1, b2) and I want to set b2 "invisible"; b1 takes j1 commands and launches them while b2 takes last line of j2. I tried to put in first line b2's public void ActionPerformed

```
b1.doClick();  
TakeLastLineJTextArea(j2);
```

b1 do work, it writes on j2 some output, output that I want to take with `TakeLastLineJTextArea(j2);` 
but it doesn't take last output because instead it takes previous output.
It works like this:

j2 before the click = "Welcome" 
j2 after the click = "Welcome (new line) output"

`TakeLastLineJTextArea(j2);` doesn't take last line (output).
Is there a way to do this or I must click the two buttons everytime?

```
public static void TakeLastLineJTextArea(JTextArea j){

    String [] array = j.getText().split("\\r?\\n");
    int last = array.length;
    switch (array[last-1]){
    case "output" : 
        Cambiostanza(  1,label1);
        Cambiopiantina(1,label2);
        break;
    case "output1" : 
        Cambiopiantina(2,label3);

        break;
    default: 
        System.out.println("Error");

        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Post TakeLastLineJTextArea() method.

Comment: I posted it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TakeLastLineJTextArea` method gets all text from `JTextArea` via `j.getText()` method as one string later you are using `split("\\r?\\n")` method to get one line of text, in your example j2 will have text:

```
"Welcome (new line) Output = some output"
```

after split you will get in `array[last-1]`:

```
" Output = some output"
```

and you are using this in switch to compare with `"output"` and `"output1"`.

This will not work.

You can use last line `array[last-1]` and after this you should do another split by whitespaces for example:

```
String lastLine = array[ last - 1 ].trim();
String[] splitedLine = lastLine.split( "\\s+" );
last = splitedLine.length;
switch( splitedLine[ last - 1 ] )
{
        case "output":
            Cambiostanza( 1, label1 );
            Cambiopiantina( 1, label2 );
            break;
        case "output1":
            Cambiopiantina( 2, label3 );
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println( "Error" );

            break;
}
```

With this code you should end in `case "output":`.

Although I'm not fully understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I edited the example. The problem is that the function doesn't take last line but always the "welcome". Thank you for your help.

Comment: Print out j.getText() to console in first line of TakeLastLineJTextArea method. And post result.